# Pushing built files to repository

Tags: git, github, npm, bower

I want a repository (on GitHub) to be used for two different purposes: for development (source files) and for releases (built/release files) to be fetched by package managers (npm, Bower, etc.).

I feel uncomfortable about pushing built files, but do not see any alternative for releases. The options I see:

- Pushing built files, then let a configuration file like `bower.json` points to the files that should be downloaded by the package manager.
- Maintaining two separate repositories. Technically speaking, I am unsure how to achieve this using Git. I think the release repository should depend on the source repository and built it.

How to achieve this in the most maintainable way?

Comment: Why not use Github Releases? https://help.github.com/articles/distributing-large-binaries/

Comment: Can package managers (like npm, Bower, etc.) install and automatically update dependencies based on GitHub releases? Or do you need to manually download the archive and extract it for every new version?

Comment: What is the output of the build. Since you are talking about bower I assume its some web component like JS or CSS

Comment: Yes this is the case. The output are minified JavaScript files, used as a library by front-end apps.